# Scan Directory and Create Thumbnail Images

Tags: php, opendir

I'm creating script to scan image directory and then create thumbnail to another directory.

```
function createThumbs( $pathToImages, $pathToThumbs, $thumbWidth ) 
{
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

set_time_limit(0);
  // open the directory
  $dir = opendir( $pathToImages );

  // loop through it, looking for any/all JPG files:
  $i='1';
  while (false !== ($fname = readdir( $dir ))) {
    // parse path for the extension
    $info = pathinfo($pathToImages . $fname);
    // continue only if this is a JPEG image
        $source_file_name = basename($source_image);
        $source_image_type = substr($source_file_name, -3, 3);

        switch(strtolower($info['extension']))
        {
        case 'jpg':
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("{$pathToImages}{$fname}");
            break;

        case 'gif':
            $img = imagecreatefromgif("{$pathToImages}{$fname}");
            break;

        case 'png':
            $img = imagecreatefrompng("{$pathToImages}{$fname}");
            break;    
        }

      echo "$i : Creating thumbnail for small_$fname <br />";

      // load image and get image size
      $width = imagesx( $img );
      $height = imagesy( $img );

    // this will be our cropped image

    // copy the crop area from the source image to the blank image created above

    // calculate thumbnail size
      $new_width = $thumbWidth;
      $new_height = $thumbWidth;

      // create a new tempopary image
      $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );


      // copy and resize old image into new image 
      imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );


    switch(strtolower($info['extension']))
    {
        case 'jpg':
            imagejpeg($tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}small_$fname", 100);
            break;

        case 'gif':
            imagegif($tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}small_$fname");
            break;

        case 'png':
            imagepng($tmp_img,"{$pathToThumbs}small_$fname", 0);
            break;    
    }
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($tmp_img);
    $i++;
      }
  // close the directory
  closedir( $dir );
}
```

And We call these function with

```
createThumbs("media/normal/","media/small/",70);
```

The script work well but the problem is, i'm having about 4000 images, and the script stopped creating thumbnail on about 2400-2600 images

you can try with this links http://saharandev.co.uk/saharan/create_thumbs_small.php

anyone can help please?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'stopped creating'? Did the script stop executing? Not iterate over those images? Execute fine, but simply not do anything to those images? Throw an exception? Throw an error? A warning? On what line?

Comment: Look into the log: Did the script stop with timeout, OOM, or something else?

Comment: @Patashu: I ran the script and it stopped at `2335 : Creating thumbnail for small_S60.10700.jpg`, I recommend removing `error_reporting(0);` to show errors.

Comment: I second commenting out error_report(0), while you're debugging at least it shouldn't be in there. The other point is that set_time_limit() only works if safe_mode (PHP<5.4) is disabled. If it is enabled that call does nothing.

Comment: to all, i try the code on my localhost and it's work well create thumbnail on 7000 images, but when it's online it's will stop on 2000 images, i can't find any log on my host

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem a while ago. I'm guessing that your the PHP script execution time directive in your hosting server's `php.ini` is set to a lower time value than whats needed to complete your processing tasks

To prevent the script from timing out, you need to increase the execution time of the processing script. You can do this from within your script or within your function. Here is an example:

```
function createThumbs( $pathToImages, $pathToThumbs, $thumbWidth ) 
{
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
  ... Your code here ...
}
```

If you still run into errors, try increasing `max_execution_time` to a higher value.

OR

Check if you have files other than `.jpeg`, `.gif` and `.png` in your source directory and delete them. It could be that a `.bmp` or a `Thumbs.db` file that's causing the errors. I mentioned `Thumbs.db` because Windows normally generates this file in folders with videos or pics.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I figured I'd add my experience to this.
If you're executing the script via a browser, the timeout thing is going to be an issue.  As I thought about it, I figured out the easiest solution without altering server settings and that's to use AJAX.

So by using jQuery AJAX, you can have jQuery trigger the PHP script to process one photo at a time, then report back the status.  You can have the javascript update a "list" or something, so you can see where it is at in the process of all of the photos.  So it would go something like this: jQuery sends command to process next file > PHP processes file, then reports back > jQuery handles response, then repeats the process.

The biggest drawback to this is that the browser has to stay open until all files are complete.  You can overcome the limits easily by running the script via the command prompt, but that's a bit more complicated from my experience.

Anyways, I hope that helps others in solving how to iterate over many photos and overcome the limitations, especially when you cannot access or change the server settings.